# onmouseleave won't work within onmousemove

Tags: javascript, html, onmousemove

I have a `div` with a `onmousemove` that I use to make an object follow the cursor. Within this `div` I have another `div` with a `onmouseleave`. The problem is that that the `onmouseleave` will only work if I move out the cursor from the object very fast. However, if I remove the `onmousemove` the `onmouseleave` starts to work correctly. How can i get `onmousemove` and `onmouseleave` to work at the same time?

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div onmousemove="cursorMove(event)" id="main">
        <p id="title">...</p>
        <div onmouseleave="gameOver()" id="light"></div>
        <div id="cursor"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="moveLight()">move</button>
    <button onclick="startGame()">start</button>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

The JavaScript

```
function cursorMove(event) {
    document.getElementById("cursor").style.top = event.clientY - 14;
    document.getElementById("cursor").style.left = event.clientX - 14;
    document.getElementById("cursor").style.opacity = '1';
}
function gameOver() {
    console.log("Game Over");
    document.getElementById("light").style.top = 245 + 'px';
    document.getElementById("light").style.left = 238 + 'px';
    document.getElementById("title").style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = 'Enter the light';
    gameActive = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with inside : `onmousemove` .Both a function are run at the time of `mousemove`

```
function cursorMove(event) {
  document.getElementById("light").onmouseleave();
}
```

or

```
<div onmousemove="cursorMove(event),gameOver()" id="main">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your whole scripting code, but I think you are trying to call the function `cursorMove` and `gameOver` from non-global context. You are using inline event handlers and your functions must be in a window execution context.

Try different approach. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4hkkm7k5/.

Besides, inline event handlers may not be a good idea. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these

Comment: I tried to replace the inline events with the addEventListner, but it didn't make any difference, unfortunately.